# CSS transition of border-width

Tags: css, angular, css-animations

I have the following code:

```
<div class="bordered" [ngStyle]="row.sticked ? {'border-left': '5px solid' + row.sticked } : null">
```

if `row.sticked` is set, the border-left property is being assigned to `5px solid #SOME_COLOR`.

the `.bordered` class is assigned to the same element and defined as below:

```
.bordered {
  transition: border-left-width 0.1s linear;
}
```

The transition works well, but when `row.sticked` becomes `false` and the border left is removed, there is no transition. (border appears -> transition works, border disappears -> removed immediately, no transition).

I tried to apply `border-left: 0` to the same `div` (I had a guess that the transition is not working if there is no border at all) but the transition from border-left: 5px to 0 is still not working.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Angular's ngStyle is working with a key:value pair, so your ternary condition should either look like `[style.border-left]="row.sticked ? '5px solid' + row.sticked"` or `[ngStyle]="{'border-left': row.sticked ? '5px solid' + row.sticked}"`

Comment: @standby954 Thanks! Much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngStyle is keyValue type so I use `row.sticked` to toggle the value of the `border-left` style

```
<div 
[ngStyle]="{'border-left': row.sticked ? ('20px solid '+row.sticked) : ('0px solid '+row.sticked) }"
class="bordered">

    border element

</div>

<button (click)="row.sticked = 'red' ">show</button>
<button (click)="row.sticked = '' ">hide</button>
```

> for `row.sticked` you may use it as flag (`true`,`false`) so when you toggle it to false you don't get a black border

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5i83b)